How to derive Lewis Riesenfeld phase?
I am reading the original paper on Lewis Riesenfeld invariant and I am struggling to derive the phase:
$$
\hbar \delta_{\kappa \kappa'} \frac{d \alpha_{\lambda \kappa}}{dt} = \left \langle \lambda, \kappa' \left \lvert i \hbar \frac{\partial}{\partial t} - H \right \rvert \lambda, \kappa \right \rangle
\, .
$$
I managed to derive the preceding results but I keep getting stuck on this. Can someone please provide a few more of the steps that the paper skips?
Also it would also help if someone could explain how the phases help to show that eigenstates of an invariant are solutions to schrodinger equation.
